# Split View Controller showing only one view (Xcode 6)

Tags: xcode, view, split, controller

I'm trying to get the split view controller working properly but apparently there's a bug in there or I'm missing something.

First of all, I've started a blank OSX Obj-C application, and in the Storyboard I've dragged the split view controller. Next, I've linked the segues from the main window controller to the split view and added two labels.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aZyw.png

When I build the project, it shows only the second page. Not to mention strange window size in the final build.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqRqr.png

I've tried everything. 
This occurs in both vertical and horizontal split view.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue myself today, but it's just the split line wasn't initiated properly.

To see, this, once you run your app, move your mouse toward the edge of the window and drag it, you will now see another view emerging.[image: I put my mouse (not shown) on the left edge and start dragging][image: There you see another split view]

To my best knowledge, I do not know how to fix this in IB or in code. Apparently `NSSplitViewController` does not have a property like `UISplitViewControllerAutomaticDimension`. Would appreciate if someone can contribute to this.

*Edited*: Found an answer via another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664044/trouble-with-nssplitview-starting-sizes-storyboards-and-swift). Basically, try to add some constraints to the subviews inside each view and that should prevent the size of a view to be zero. In my toy example, adding margin constraints to my buttons worked out well.