# Initial window with no width in application using Storyboards

Tags: xcode, macos, storyboard, window, nssplitview

I am trying to understand Storyboard in XCode.
I have created a new Mac OS X Application from template and defined a simple Storyboard, like in the following image:

[image]

The problem is that when I run the application, my window looks like this:

[image]

I have to resize it to see RIGHT and LEFT part of vertical split view.
I have defined height and with of my window so I don't know why is this happening and I really don't know why is this window correctly shown with view controller below instead of split view controller.

[image]

[image]

What I am doing wrong with split view controller?

Comment: This is not related to Swift. I experience the exact same problem in an Objective-C project. I removed the Swift reference in title and tags.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to add *width constraints* with a minimum width to the views in each side of the SplitView.

I got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27667775/2012262) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27664044/2012262).